# Gerrit: no git fetch/pull info in download section

Tags: git, gerrit

## Context

We use Gerrit (v2.11.1) for our code reviews, but after a recent update the 'git fetch' info is missing from the Download section. I mean the git pull/fetch info as explained in the manual: https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.9/user-review-ui.html#download

This is a pain since now I cannot fetch/pull the code under review and tinker with it. I can download the files btw, the links to the patch files and the archives are there.

### Question

I tried searching/googling the answer, but it seems that no-one has reported this problem.

So my questions are:

- Anybody else with this problem?
- Did we do something wrong with the installation of Gerrit.
- Is this a known bug of our Gerrit version 2.11.1?
- Is there a workaround. Seems like it should be possible to construct the specific branch info from gerrit (some combination of review nr etc).
- someone with a solution?

Comment: Have you checked the [download](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#download) settings?

Comment: Ah thanks, that looks like a good pointer. I will check it out when I am back at work.

Comment: checked it, seems ok. Even with empty settings it does not work. Seems like a bug. I will ask the Gerrit team.

Comment: For reference for future users with the same problem: apparently we did not install a plugin needed for the downloads correctly

Comment: You probably mean the [download commands](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/download-commands/) plugin.